# Speed up R-code to fill in vector with strings based on other dataframe

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

I have a very large dataframe (`df0`) with a column for province with 12 unique provinces and a column for party which is empty (`NAs`). I have another dataframe (`votes`) where I have a row for each party per province, and the proportion of people that voted for it. Find a minimal example below:

```
df0 = data.frame(geo_prov = rep(c("prov_a","prov_b","prov_c"), each = 100),
                 party    = NA)

votes = data.frame(geo_prov = rep(c("prov_a","prov_b","prov_c"), each = 3),
                   party    = rep(c("party_a","party_b","party_c"), times = 3),
                   prop     = c(0.5,0.3,0.2,
                                0.1,0.7,0.2,
                                0.2,0.1,0.7))
```

I now want to fill in the `df0$party` column with the parties so that for every province, the proportion of filled-in parties is equal to that in the `votes` df. I have code that works (see below) but is very slow on a large dataset (13 million records, 20 parties).

```
for(prov in unique(df0$geo_prov)){
  n_prov = nrow(df0[df0$geo_prov == prov,])
  vote_freqs = c()
  
  for(party in unique(votes$party)){
    vote_freqs = c(vote_freqs, rep(party, each = floor(votes[votes$geo_prov == prov & votes$party == party,]$prop*n_prov)))
    
  }
  
  df0$party[df0$geo_prov == prov] = vote_freqs
  
}
```

I would like to improve the code to speed this up. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df0 |>
  mutate(pct = row_number() / n(), .by = geo_prov) |>
  select(-party) |>
  left_join(votes |>
              mutate(cuml = cumsum(prop), .by = geo_prov),
            join_by(geo_prov, closest(pct <= cuml)))
```

(I'm seeing I don't have this exactly identical (due I think to floating point equality testing), but with a little tweaking expect this should match, and much faster.)

Answer (score 2):

`Dplyr` and `Data.table` has been known for speed and minimal memory usage. Some could [argue](https://tysonbarrett.com/jekyll/update/2019/10/06/datatable_memory/) that one is better than the other but i believe both has got their respective strength and flavour. Below is the `data.table` approach to your question.

```
library(data.table)
# Calculate the 'pct' column in df0 while dropping 'party'
df0[, pct := rowid(geo_prov) / .N, by = geo_prov]
df0[, party := NULL]

# Calculate the cumulative sum in votes 
votes[, cuml := cumsum(prop), by = geo_prov]

# Perform the left join
result <- df0[votes[pct <= cuml, closest(.I)], on = "geo_prov"]
```